# Xamarin forms: Grouping a listview by date

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I want to be able to show a list of events in a listview grouped by date.

The items on the list already contains the time, so the header of each group should just be the date.

One way to solve this is to convert the models DateTime into a string with the format "yyyy/MM/dd" and give the group this title. But I want to display "18/02-2017" to the user.

Also if it is today I would like it to have the group name "Today".

I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

James Montemagno has a nice tutorial on grouping in a ListView at:

http://motzcod.es/post/94643411707/enhancing-xamarinforms-listview-with-grouping

In your case you could use what he talks about in his tutorial and add a special readonly property to your model. That property returns a string in the required format or "Today" if the current date matches the date field. You can then use that field to group on. Sorting can be done on the actual date property, which should put Today on top of your list.

```
public string GroupDate
{
    get 
    {
        if(YourDateProperty.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
            return "Today";
        else
            return YourDateProperty.ToString("dd/MM-yyyy");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the easy way is using a custom converter:

```
class DateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
        if (date.Equals(DateTime.Today))
        {
            return "Today";
        }
        return date.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0') + @"/" + date.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "-" + date.Year;
    }
}
```

With this converter you get both, "today" if the value is today, and the date with format dd/MM-yyyy

You can use the converter like this:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:DateConverter x:Key="DateConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<StackLayout>
    <ListView
        GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}"
        IsGroupingEnabled="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Events}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

And this is the result:

[image: ListView grouped]

I hope this can help you.